# How can I make some data on a Google Sheets auto-sorting?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, sorting

Let's say I want Google Sheets to automagically sort some data, for example column `C`.

How do I do that?

I know that I can manually sort data by right-clicking and selecting *Sort data*, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 72):

You can use [the `sort()` function](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_range.html#sort) for that, but you have to have your data in one place, and an automatically sorted copy of that data in another place.

For example, say I have Sheet1 with my data:

```
   | A    | B    | C
=====================
 1 | This | this | 2
 2 | Is   | is   | 1
 3 | Test | test | 3
```

Then in Sheet2, cell A1, I would put this function:

> =sort(Sheet1!A:C, 3, TRUE)

This would show my data, but sorted by column C (the third column), ascending.

```
   | A    | B    | C
=====================
 1 | Is   | is   | 1
 2 | This | this | 2
 3 | Test | test | 3
```

Answer (score 64):

It is also possible to use [Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to achieve automatic in-place sorting of the data.

This may be more difficult to achieve and is more error-prone (I'd still go for William Jackson's solution, +1 BTW), but I thought it was interesting enough to show.

I have a sheet that looks like this:

[image: auto-sorting sheet]

I added a new script using these steps:

1. In the menu, go to *Tools* -> *Script Editor...*
2. Select *Create a new project*
3. In the empty code window that appears, paste the following code which will be run automatically whenever a cell is edited:

   ```
   function onEdit(event){
     var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
     var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

     var columnToSortBy = 4;
     var tableRange = "B3:E9";

     if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
       var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
       range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
     }
   }
   ```
4. Go back to the sheet and start playing around with the values to see the table sort automatically each time

**Note:**

In the above script:

- The value `4` represents the index of column D (the `Value` column - the one that's going to be sorted)
- The value `"B3:E9"` represents the table range (excluding the header row)

Your table will most likely differ from mine, so these values should be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: I tried yours [edited]
function onEdit(event){ var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet(); var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell(); var columnToSortBy = 4; var tableRange = "A2:F99"; if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){ var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange); range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } ); }
} but keep getting an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2)
which is the following code: var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
any ideas? NM, only get the error when running from the script page, but it works properly on the actual spreadshee

Comment: but keep getting an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2)
which is the following code: var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
any ideas? NM, only get the error when running from the script page, but it works properly on the actual spreadsheet. Now question... its sorting A-Z, how do I change it to auto-sort Z-A?
thanks

Comment: @drizzt09 When you call the method you probably specify `null` for the `event` parameter, which is otherwise properly populated by the Google Spreadsheet infrastructure when a real event is triggered.

Comment: @drizzt09 to change the sort order, change the `range.sort` line like this: `range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } ); `. For more sorting options see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#sort

Comment: @w0lf
Thank you that worked perfect. now I would like to add to it or have a seperate function that performs the exact same function but on open or refresh. So when I open/refresh the excel sheet it will auto sort 4th column descending the same as when I edit the code in column 4 with your current code. Thanks

Comment: @drizzt09 have a look at the events exposed by a Google Spreadsheet: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#Simple. What you need is the `onOpen()` event

Comment: Here's a more **generic version that supports ordering and multiple columns**: [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/YatharthROCK/e1c7634946a46c266872)

Comment: Is it possible to sort with multiple criteria too? e.g. Sort column D, then column C, then column B.

Comment: @Benjamin sure, the script can easily be adjusted to do that, because `range.sort` allows sorting by multiple columns. Take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)).

Comment: If you want a specific sheet instead of applying the sort to every sheet, replace the first function line with this:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Income");

Comment: Does this automatically run if a cell is updated via =GoogleFinance() or similar?

Answer (score 16):

Another option without a script is:

```
=QUERY(A1:C3,"SELECT * ORDER BY C")
```

The range is restricted (A1:C3) because where the order is ascending blank entries will appear first.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a generic script that will autosort based on the 1st column, and assumes a Header row.

To create a script:

- In the menu, go to Tools -> Script Editor...

In the empty code window, paste the following code, which will run automatically whenever a cell is edited:

```
 // LinkBack to this script:
 // http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-spreadsheet-auto-sorting/43036#43036

 /**
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Comment: I found I had to `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` instead of what's here.

Comment: This works great, but how can I edit this so it only sorts on a single sheet in doc?

Comment: doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 7):

It can be done using Google App Script. The script will automatically sort whenever there is a change in sheet data.

On your Google Sheet:
Choose Tools –> Script Editor and paste the below script and save.

Replace the SHEET_NAME, SORT_DATA_RANGE and SORT_ORDER variables with corresponding values.

```
SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A1:C999";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 3, ascending: false},  // 3 = column number, sorting by descending order
{column: 1, ascending: true}, // 1 = column number, sort by ascending order 
{column: 2, ascending: true}
];

function onEdit(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Source: https://www.idiotinside.com/2018/06/08/sort-multiple-columns-google-sheets-apps-script/

Answer (score 1):

### Using the script solution, but sort on more than one column

I wanted to sort by a dropdown menu column and then by date.

To do so, modify the "range.sort" line of either of Cristian or geekspotz's code snippets like so:

```
// Sorts descending by edited column, then ascending by column 1 
// Note the use of an array

range.sort([{column: columnToSortBy, ascending: false}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
```

The difference is adding the straight brackets around your whole statement (array) and separating the sorts by commas.

*Sort code modification pulled from Serge's Stack Overflow answer here*:
[Automatic Sorting On Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563652/automatic-sorting-on-sheets)

Answer (score 1):

Here i created an auto sorting script and spreadsheet(it require a bit of work on the sheet, a copy paste of the code and setting your ranges. 
Its based on multiple stackexchange answer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LDohwCuy8HZg4YCQEOuWmgpY_WG2BVh_aH-i4JGM5BE/edit#gid=0

Its record and gets the value of the range you focus on at last edit compare it to value now after  actual edit and if different it sort the table.

Answer (score 0):

This function seems to work for me:

```
function sortRangeByColumn(range, columnNum, direction) {
  range
  .offset(1, 0, range.getNumRows() - 1) // to ignore the header row https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAppsScript/comments/di13bl/google_spreadsheet_script_how_to_sort_a_range_of/f3t6c0h/
  .sort([ // https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138495/27487
    { 
      column: columnNum,
      ascending: direction.toUpperCase() === 'ASC'
    }
  ]); // https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25570/27487
}
```

Comment: Since the question isn't about Google Apps Script, please explain how this answers the question and how this script should be used.

Answer (score 0):

### Easily-configurable multi-column sort that automatically re-runs upon edit

Example workbook: [Google Sheets Apps Script for automatic saved multi-column sorting (PUBLIC)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ssgPxNs-me5e1dqWq_SUqcwv1h81J7VnTtWDMWswACs/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  applySorting("mainTable");
}

function applySorting(rangeName){   
  // See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158165/27487   
  const sortingRulesRange = getRangeByName(rangeName + "_sorting");
  const dataRange = getRangeByName(rangeName);
  const sortingRulesArray = [];
  const numRows = sortingRulesRange.getNumRows();
  for (let r = 1; r <= numRows; r+=1) {
    const colNum = sortingRulesRange.getCell(r, 1).getValue();
    if (colNum) {
      const direction = sortingRulesRange.getCell(r, 2).getValue();
      Logger.log(direction);
      const ascending = direction.toUpperCase() === 'ASC';
      sortingRulesArray.push({column: colNum, ascending});
    }
  }

  Logger.log(sortingRulesArray);
  dataRange.sort(sortingRulesArray);
  toast("Sorted " + rangeName + ".");
}

function getRangeByName(rangeName) {  
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(rangeName);
}

function toast(message) {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.toast(message);
}
```

I made the example workbook public so that you can clone (make a copy) of it without even requesting permission from me.

Comment: Since the question isn't about Google Apps Script, please explain how this answers the question and how this script should be used.

Answer (score -1):

Google Sheets has [Filters](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) for this very reason and doesn't require you to make a new sheet in your document.

**Documentation:** https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681

Comment: To me, it seems like this abbreviates the process, but doesn't count as "auto-sorting". You still need to click the column header to trigger the re-sort after new data entry. Or maybe I'm missing a trick.