# How can I make some data on a Google Spreadsheet auto-sorting using onOpen?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I was working with @W0lf [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-spreadsheet-auto-sorting/26496#26496)
but I am unable to comment/continue the conversation anymore.

I am trying to use autosort function onOpen but is not working:

```
function onOpen(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "A2:F99";

  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
  }
```

@w0lf's code for onEdit is working:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "A2:F99";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to rename your variable `ss` to `sheet`:

```
function onOpen(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "A2:F99";

  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
}
```

If that does not work, try to use @w0lf's approach with the event argument:

```
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
```

**UPDATE:**
To sort by several columns just put the sorting options into an array, like so:

```
range.sort( [4, 1] ); // or
range.sort( [{ column: 4, ascending: false }, 1] ); // or
range.sort( [{ column: 4, ascending: false }, { column: 1, ascending: false }] );
```

See the google dev docs for more details: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#sort .

Comment: Thanks the following code worked:

`function onOpen(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "A2:G99";
    
  var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: false } );
}`

Now how would I go about adding a secondary column to sort by. Its currently by column 4, I would then like to sort secondary by column 1

Comment: See my update for an example.