# Auto Sort Sheet on second entry

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I loved the script put forward by [w0lf](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25570/29140) mostly it did the trick however I cannot figure out a way to have it sort only when I enter data in the second column of 4 columns it does it when I enter data in the first:

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 4;
  var tableRange = "B3:E9";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy } );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to an answer on another question? If so which question?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39075/29140) answer, you need to use the `getcolumn()`:

```
function onEdit(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sh.getActiveRange().getColumn();

  if(editedCell == 2) { 
    var range = sh.getRange("A1:D10");
    range.sort({column: 4});
  }
}
```