# OnEdit won't apply to all tabs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am running a script that automatically organizes priority in a to-do list. It works great on the current tab, but when moved to a sheet within the worksheet the same OnEdit function will not run.  Here is the code below:

```
function myFunction() {

}

function onEdit(B){
  var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var editedCell = sh0.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();

  if(editedCell == 1) { 
    var range = sh0.getRange("A4:G");
    range.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

I also have a script to delete rows when marked "completed" and it works fantastically throughout the entire sheet.

```
function myFunction() {

}
function onEdit(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for( i=1 ;i<=lastRow ; i++) { // i <= lastRow
       var status = sheet.getRange("F"+i).getValue();
    if (status == "Completed") {
          sheet.deleteRows(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by the content you added on the last edit ( [rev. 4](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/131004/4) ). By the other hand, post questions should be specific and should contain only one question. Also it's worth to note that  you could delete the `myFunction` function as it's does nothing and apparently you are not using it.

Comment: I guess I'm confused at how to get the triggering function to work. I can't seem to figure it out after reading the post probably about 30 times :(

Comment: Maybe we should start from 0. Create a new spreadsheet, add a new script project to it, delete the default code and add one an only one onEdit function. To test it edit your spreadsheet, if it works, fine you are done, right? if it doesn't work look at the execution code, then edit your question to add the details about what you did and the execution transcript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script are the following code lines

```
var sh0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
```

The above code line assigns the first sheet to `sh0`

```
var editedCell = sh0.getActiveRange().getColumnIndex();
```

The above code line gets a range from the first sheet

Try this function

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 1) { 
    var range = e.range.getSheet().getRange("A4:G");
    range.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});
  }
}
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Related questions

- [How can I make some data Autosort in a spreadsheet on edit?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39067/88163)
  Despite the title, the question is about an `onEdit` function that isn't working when it's called from the script editor.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am getting an error that says "TypeError: Cannot read property "columnStart" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")".  Any idea?

Comment: @AlejandroStory I'm sorry. It should be `e.range.columnStart` instead of `e.columnStart`. I corrected my answer. If you don't see the change please refresh your web browser tab.

Comment: ok so when I do this I get "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")". Thank you for helping me figure this out, I can tell you know more than I do about this stuff, I am a newbie :)

Comment: @AlejandroStory That is because you are running the onEdit function directly from the code editor and the event object isn't assigned.

Comment: how and where do I assign the event object?

Comment: Please read [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your last comments. If you have a follow-up question, please post it as a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, let me clarify.  I added more to my original question above that shows an OnEdit script for conditionally deleting rows that is working with all sheets.  My question to you is if you know of a script that looks like the one above that can apply to the OnEdit Script that is not working.