# Google Spreadsheet Sort Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

So I've found the following answer in regards to auto-sorting by one column, which works great
[How can I make some data on a Google Spreadsheet auto-sorting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-spreadsheet-auto-sorting/25570#25570)

However, my use case requires the sorting of two columns. One column is whole numbers, while the second column are dates. I would like to sort the whole numbers column first, then within each number sort the date.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with the following line of code:

`var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B10");`

The sort can be performed in different ways:

1. `range.sort([1,2]);`
2. `range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);`

Both ways are identical as the sort type is by default ascending, but the second option allows for different sort order when `TRUE` is changed to `FALSE`.

See reference: [range.sort](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort%28Object%29)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your answer makes sense to me. I've implemented the knowledge with success.

Comment: OK, new to this stuff...where exactly do I enter the above code?

Comment: @robb see reference the OP uses, that Will lead to An answer I gave with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party but this is what I did.

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()=='Sort by country full'){
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var columnToSortBy = 16;
    var columnToSortBy2 = 2;
    var tableRange = "A2:AU1451";
    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
      var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
      range.sort( [{ column : columnToSortBy },{column: columnToSortBy2,ascending: false }] );
    }
  }
}
```

Sorts by column 16 first which for me is countries and then by a scoring rating in column 2 descending.