# Sort randomly in a Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I found this script to sort a Google Spreadsheet but I need to sort everything randomly instead of alphabetically, is there a way to sort it randomly every time this script runs?

```
// LinkBack to this script:  // http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-spreadsheet-auto-sorting/43036#43036

/**  
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Ascending. 
 */ 
function onEdit(event){
   var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
   var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

   var columnToSortBy = 1;   var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the function `shuffleSheet` which randomly shuffles the rows of the current sheet. The actual shuffling algorithm (which is classical) is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12646864/3717023) by [Laurens Holst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310500/laurens-holst).

I imagine this is something you will not want to do on every edit, but only when the script is explicitly invoked.

```
function shuffleSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  range.setValues(shuffleArray(range.getValues()));    
}    

function shuffleArray(array) {
  var i, j, temp;
  for (i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do shuffle only in Row A?

Comment: Yes; change the line with `var range` to `var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");`

Comment: AWESOME! It worked perfectly!... Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `randomize()` function for range. I'm using user79865's code as a basis:

```
function shuffleSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  range.randomize();    
}
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#randomize()

Comment: This is indeed the simplest way. Would be nice to exclude the header row(s).

Answer (score 1):

Bookend's answer works perfectly. I had to call the function from outside of the spreadsheet though (which makes sense, given that the output changes the contents of the spreadsheet). Here's how to do that:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Extra Functions')
      .addItem('Shuffle Sheet', 'shuffleSheet')
      /*
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Sub-menu')
          .addItem('Second item', 'menuItem2'))
      */
      .addToUi();
}
```

The next time you open your spreadsheet, go to 'Extra Functions' in the menu bar and select 'Shuffle Sheet'.