# Auto sorting by multiple columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, sorting

I have a data-set which I would like to have sorted with first column 6 and then column 7.

From this post: [How can I make some data on a Google Sheets auto-sorting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7211/how-can-i-make-some-data-on-a-google-sheets-auto-sorting) I have gotten ideas about making a script.

I have made it so far it is sorting by column 6 but NOT column 7.

Any idea what I do wrong?

```
function myFunction() {

}
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 6;
  var tableRange = "A2:U";

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
  range.sort([{column: 6, ascending: true}, {column: 7, ascending: true}]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it really have to be using a script? It could be easier using a formula.

Comment: @marikamitsos because by doing it with scripts you get the added bonus of the onEdit misfiring because of it's inability to handle more than 2 edits at a time which in turn will create more stackexchange questions!

Comment: @CodeCamper Something new every day. Thanks. Looking forward for your answer

Answer (score 0):

#### Sort by columns 6 and 7 when column 6 is edited

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 6) {
    let range = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 21);
    range.sort([{ column: 6, ascending: true }, { column: 7, ascending: true }]);
  }
}
```