# How on Google sheets can I auto sort multiple Columns on multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

So I work in a secondary school, as such we're trying to make a temporary register that will auto sort. We therefore have a sheet for each year group. So I need multiple sheets to auto sort based on multiple columns, I've found information on how to do 1 column on multiple sheets or multiple columns on 1 sheet unfortunately I don't understand coding well enough to put these things together. I can manage to alter code to make it match what I'm working with but not stick two bits together.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do yo mean by coding/code? Does it means writing spreadsheet formulas or writing code in Google Apps Scripts?

Comment: I mean writing code in Google apps scripts.

Comment: See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130190/88163) to [How can I make some data on a Google Sheets auto-sorting?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7211/88163)